# How to read ".resources" file generated by "resgen.exe"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resgen

By using resgen.exe, I can generate the "resources" file from a txt file. I can use the "resources" file in WPF, however I am not sure how can I populate the value in "cshtml" file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Design-time `.resx` files are compiled into binary `.resources` blobs within .NET assemblies that are then read with the `ResourceManager` class. These blobs are essentially just key/value dictionaries.

Like so:

```
ResourceManager res = new ResourceManager("NameOfEmbedded.resources", GetType().GetExecutingAssembly());
String localizedString = res.GetString("resourceKey");
```

In Visual Studio will create a strongly-typed wrapper around each (non-localized) `.resx` file so you don't need to remember each resource's string key and also makes it available from a static context, so all you need to do is:

```
String localizedString = Resources.ResourceKey;
```

(Assuming `Resources` is the name of your `.resx`-wrapper class)

In your `.cshtml` files, to render localized text, use the `@` syntax to render accordingly:

```
<p>Hello this next text is localized: @Resources.ResourceKey</p>
```

This is different to WPF where you would do it like this:

```
xmlns:r="MyNamespace.Properties"

<TextBlock Content="{x:Static r:Resources.ResourceKey}" />
```